# how to insert binary data to QuestDb using influxdb line protocol?

Tags: questdb

how to insert binary data to QuestDb using influxdb line protocol?

there is no documentation on how to insert binary filed value
https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/ilp/columnset-types/#string

well maybe i could do strings

`sometable "abc\0\0\0\"defg .. binary data" 154564564456`

I am hesitant that inserting as string could ruin binary parts of inserted values.

Is there a binary way to do it, or will it work correctly if i insert values as a string?

will it create a binary column automatically?

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid that QuestDB doesn't support binary column values in Influx Line Protocol (ILP). Only string, symbol, numeric, boolean, and timestamp column types are supported by ILP. You may use PG wire to insert binary data.

If you'd like to see this feature in ILP, could you open an issue in our GH repo?
https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/

Comment: thanks for answering, i have created an issue, https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/1925